# Why does it refuse to output the if-statement when a prime number of 10-20 is inputted?

Tags: c++

I have tried to analyze my code several times but still couldn't figure out the problem why it doesn't show "product is in tens" when 10-20 is entered.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, t;
    double f = 1;
    
    cout << "Input a digit: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    cout << n << "! is: ";
        for (t = 1; t <= n; t++) {
            f = f * t;
            cout << t;
                if (n > t) {
                    cout << " x ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " = " << f << endl;
                }
        }
        if (f < 10) {
            cout << "The product is in ones." << endl;
        }
        if ((f < 100) == (f > 10)) {
            cout << "The product is in tens." << endl;
        }
        if ((f < 1000) == (f > 100)) {
            cout << "The product is in hundreds." << endl;
        }
        if ((f < 10000) == (f > 1000)) {
            cout << "The product is in thousands." << endl;
        }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Say, the input is anywhere from 10 to 20.

```
Input: 10

Result: 10! is:1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10=3628800
```

Shouldn't it say "the product is in tens."?

Normally, if I input, say, '5', it would come out as:

```
5! is:1x2x3x4x5=120
the product is in hundreds
```

Edit: I discovered a tiny problem where it should have capitalized 'T' on "The product is in []" but instead it results in "the" i.e., lowercase 't' should be uppercase letter.

Comment: you need > 9 OR >=10

Comment: But 10! isn't in tens...

Comment: @Daniel which block are you referring to? I just did and it is still the same.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts tens or ones or hundreds, I just need the code running smoothly

Comment: If analyzing the code doesn't work, and often it doesn't as bad assumptions made writing code tend to follow through and become bad assumptions when reasoning about code, step through it in a debugger and keep an eye out for where the program foes something unexpected like store the wrong value or take the wrong path. The unexpected is either a bad expectation or a mistake in the program and both need to be fixed.

Comment: Stylistic note: `(f < 100) == (f > 10)` is a little confusing compared to `(f < 100) && (f > 10)`. In this case they happen to be equivalent because there's no way for `f < 100` and `f > 10` to both be false, but in general it doesn't look like `==` is what you mean for this sort of comparison.

Comment: @Nandostyle worked fine when input is around 10 to 20 but when I tried 1111 as an input, it shows "the product is in ones" and "the product is in thousands" both at the same time.

Comment: Disregard my comment I misinterpreted you. Follow @Nathan Pierson's recommendation. your problem is that you need to use proper comparators.

Comment: 10 factorial is 3628800 so it is higher than any of the ranges you specified in your long sequence of if statements.  The highest range you specified is 1000 to 10000, and you print "thousands" for that range.  Since 3628800 is larger than 10000, it is not in that range or any of the other ranges you specified in your code. You need to simply add more cases if you want to print a similar message for 3628800.

Comment: `((f < 100) == (f > 10))` The first one is true, ten is less than 100, but the second is false, ten is not greater than 10. So why should they be equivalent in value?

Comment: @NathanPierson re: "there's no way", unless `f` was `float` or `double`, in which case the value `NAN` would cause all numerical comparisons to be false.

Comment: How is the product `1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10 (3628800)` _"in the tens"_? If it's because `n` is `10`, then why should `n = 20` be in the tens?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's a mistake I was afraid to clarify since everyone's already commented on my question. It should be 10! = millions form.

Answer (score -1):

As your code notes:

```
10! == 1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10 == 3,628,800
```

That number is in the millions, not tens. So it makes sense that your conditional fails, since 3628800 is not less than 100.